# jqgrid functionality using Struts2 mobile tags

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, struts2, jqgrid, struts2-jquery

I want to display grid on mobile using struts2 mobile tags. I searched on net about grid but all the examples are for web application using                                                                                     sjg:grid 
tag. As I am new to Struts2 mobile tags can anyone please help me about how to display jqgrid using Struts2 mobile tags.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: What is *mobile tags* ?